# Why I cant query sub-collection or a document from a sub-collection in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have this query where I am trying to get a document from a sub-collection but it doesnt get anything, neither it shows any error. Could it be an issue in Firebase side or am I doing something wrong here:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
let ref = db.collection('myCollection').doc('EzGNfNl63LQvjdauFWosG08Ishj2').collection('privat').doc('privat');
        ref.get()
            .then(doc => {  //it doesnt continue to next line, just executes this one
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("Doc exists:", doc.data())
                }else{
                    console.log("Doc deostn exists:")
                }

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('Error getting restaurant data: ', error);
            })
```

However, if I try to query only a document from the collection then it works:

```
let ref = db().collection('myCollection').doc('EzGNfNl63LQvjdauFWosG08Ishj2');
```

**EDIT: Screenshot of my database added**
[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to show a screenshot of the document that you're trying to fetch.   Also please be clear what you mean by "it doesnt continue to next line, just executes this one".  What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Is that code as it is written? It seems you began using a dot operator on the first line then moved onto a variable declaration. If so, that could be your problem.

Comment: Are u sure the document has the same name as the collection?

Comment: @DougStevenson when I am debugging i put a breakpoint in all those lines, and I can iterate through each one until I reach `.then(doc => {` then when I hit F8 it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @PeterHaddad I am very sure, I named them like that, and I copied the name of both by selecting not typing myself.

Comment: @bmmf are u using db() or db?

Comment: Use logging to determine what is happening at each stage, and edit the question to show what the logs output.  You will need to make it very clear what your code is doing, and how that is different than what you expect.  Also please show a screenshot of the document you are trying to get - we need to be able to see what is in your database.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am using logging `console.log("Doc exists:", doc.data())` but unfortunetly never reaches there so i am not able to print anything. I will take a screenshot of my data now.

Comment: @DougStevenson please check the screenshot I posted.

Comment: What is "RriNshpUsers"?  Refresh that page and look again.

Comment: @DougStevenson nvm that I forgot to edit the picture there because I am using different name for that collection for better understanding. "RriNshpUsers" is indeed "myCollection".

Comment: @DougStevenson check the screenshot again. I updated it.

Comment: Looks like you edited the screenshot instead of taking another actual screenshot.

Comment: @DougStevenson exactly!

Comment: OK, without an actual screenshot with actual data that hasn't been doctored, I'm not sure we can help.  We need to see that your query matches your data.  If it doesn't match, your query will simply return no data.

Comment: @DougStevenson I said don't mind the first screenshot please, forget about that one, this is the actual representation of my data. The collection is called "myCollection".

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore.
let ref = db().collection('myCollection').doc('EzGNfNl63LQvjdauFWosG08Ishj2').collection('privat').doc('privat');
        ref.get()
            .then(doc => {  //it doesnt continue to next line, just executes this one
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("Doc exists:", doc.data())
                }else{
                    console.log("Doc deostn exists:")
                }

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('Error getting restaurant data: ', error);
            })
```

Into this:

```
const db = firebase.firestore();
let ref = db.collection('myCollection').doc('EzGNfNl63LQvjdauFWosG08Ishj2').collection('privat').doc('privat');
        ref.get()
            .then(doc => {  //it doesnt continue to next line, just executes this one
                if (doc.exists) {
                    console.log("Doc exists:", doc.data())
                }else{
                    console.log("Doc deostn exists:")
                }

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log('Error getting restaurant data: ', error);
            })
```

`firestore()` is a method and `db` is a constant.

Comment: The question gives an example of using `db()` that works. It's probably just a typo.

Comment: @bmmf if you check ur image it seems `EzGNfNl63LQvjdauFWosG08Ishj2` isn't a direct document under `myCollection`.

Comment: @PeterHaddad check the updated screenshot, nvm the previous one.